# Need help with an operation on finite length $A$-modules and Grothendieck Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, dedekind-domain

I'm reading Serre's local field, chapter 1 section 5, Norm and Inclusion Homomorphisms.

In particular, he defines the operation $\chi_A$ from the category of finite length $A$-modules to the collection of ideals of $A$ where $A$ is Dedekind domain.

Here goes: since $M$, a finite length $A$-module, admits composition serries $$0=M_0\subseteq...\subseteq M_m=M$$ with $M_i/M_{i-1}\cong A/p_i$ where $p_i$ is non-zero prime ideal of $A$. We define $$\chi_A(M)=\prod_{i=1}^mp_i$$ We know by Jordan-Holder Theorem this operation is well-defined.

Then he mentions an example as follows:

> When $M=b/a$ where $a,b$ are fractional ideals with $a\subset b$, one has $\chi_A(M)=ab^{-1}$. In particular, $\chi_A(A/a)=a$ if $a\subset A$.

I want to have a better grasp on this concept so decided to word by word show the claim, starting with the particular case. Here is my attempt:

> Let us first exam the claim $\chi_A(A/a)=a$. Note since $a\subseteq A$, it admits prime factorization, say $a=Q_1Q_2...Q_n$ where $Q_i$'s
>   are all prime ideals with possible repetition, then we have the
>   composition series $$0=a/a\subseteq Q_1Q_2...Q_{n-1}/a\subseteq Q_1...Q_{n-2}/a\subseteq...\subseteq Q_1/a\subseteq A/a$$ In
>   particular, we claim that $(Q_1...Q_{k-1}/a)/(Q_1...Q_k/a)\cong A/Q_k$. Indeed, note $(Q_1...Q_{k-1}/a)/(Q_1...Q_k/a)\cong Q_1...Q_{k-1}/Q_1...Q_k$ and so it suffices to show that equal $A/Q_k$.
>
> To show this, we claim that if $I$ and $J$ are distinct comaximal ideals of $A$, then $I/IJ\cong A/J$. Indeed, note the map $\phi:I\to A/J$ is surjective where $\phi(a)=a+J$. Indeed, take $x+J\in A/J$ be
>   arbitrary, we have $x=i+j$ where $i\in I$ and $j\in J$, hence $x-i\in J$, i.e. $x+J=i+J$ and so $\phi(i)=x+J$ as desired. Now, it is evident
>   that the kernel of this map is $IJ$, i.e. we indeed have $I/IJ\cong A/J$. Thus, if $Q_{k-1}$ and $Q_k$ are distinct, we have $Q_1....Q_{k-1}/Q_{1}...Q_{k-1}Q_k$ satisfy the claim in this
>   paragraph, i.e. $Q_1...Q_{k-1}/Q_1...Q_k\cong A/Q_k$.
>
> Next, we deal with $I$ and $J$ are the same. This is the same as showing $P/P^2\cong A/P$ where $P$ is prime. First, consider the
>   localization at $P$, we have $PA_P$ becomes principal ideals, i.e.
>   $PA_P=\pi A_P$ and so $P^2A_P=\pi^2 A_P$. On the other hand, consider
>   the map $\phi:PA_P\to A_P/PA_P$ given by $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\pi}$ with
>   the kernel equal $P^2A_P$.

Here I got stuck as not sure how to continue, I could show that $PA_P/P^2A_P$ can be embedded into the module $A_P/PA_P$ and I think $A_P/PA_P$ is isomorphic to $A/P$ based on arguments [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120905/localisation-of-quotients-of-dedekind-domains). In addition, note since $A/P$ is a simple module while $PA_P/P^2A_P$ is a non-zero submodule, we must have $PA_P/P^2A_P$ equal $A/P$. However, even this, I cannot conclude $PA_P/P^2A_P$ is just the same as $P/P^2$, can we?

Thus, here goes my questions,

Q1: How could we show the two examples holds (the one I just showed partially and the more general case)?

Q2: Can someone tell me what this operation $\chi_A$ is? Also, if you could point out some text explain this and relative concepts I would be much appreciated.

Comment: $PA_P/P^2A_P$ is not "equsl" to $A/P$, rather is is isomoprhic to it. Note that $A_P$ is a DVR so all its ideals are principal.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yeah, they are isomorphic and that is all I need. However, my localization argument only shows the localized ideals is isomorphic to it, rather than the original one... That's what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Can you show $P^nA_p/P^{n+1}A_P\cong A_P/PA_P$ as $A_P$-modules?

Comment: I don't see how that helps to lift the local thing to global... Also, since we have $PA_P/P^2A_P\cong A_P/PA_P$, isn't it just an induction process to make your claim (to a higher power) holds?

Comment: $\chi_A$ is defined on the middle of page 16. As you observed, it's pretty easy to show $p_p/p_p^2$ is isomorphic to $A_p/p_p$ because everyone is principal. We know that localization is compatible with quotients, $A_p/p_p \cong (A/p)_p$. The latter is isomorphic to $A/p$ because it is the localization of $A/p$ at the set of elements not in $p$, i.e. the localization of a field at its nonzero elements, but those elements are already invertible so localization doesn't change it.

Comment: @TokenToucan Yes, I indeed showed the localised quotient is isomorphic to $A/p$, however, I think I still need to make an argument to show the global case, right? Like $p/p^2\cong A/p$.

Comment: $p/p^2\cong p_p/p_p^2 \cong A_p/p_p \cong A/p$